# Using Ray Multiprocessing on Docker

Tags: python, docker, multiprocessing, ray

I am trying to parallelize processes using Ray in a docker container.

```
from ray.util.multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool(self.n_cores) as pool:
   pool.starmap(func=func, iterable=list_of_parameters)
```

while it is perfectly working locally, when it gets run in the docker container, the following error occurs:

✗  failed cod_simulation-run
Job 'cod_simulation-run' failed:
| AttributeError: 'StreamCapture' object has no attribute 'fileno'
Write "details cod_simulation-run" to inspect the error.
Processed 1 jobs (1 failed).

I was previously performing the same thing with python multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

with mp.Pool(self.n_cores) as pool:
   pool.starmap(func=func, iterable=list_of_parameters)
```

and this worked both locally and in the docker container. But for efficiency reasons, I would prefer to stick to Ray.

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /project_name
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

RUN find .

ENV DISABLE_CONTRACTS=1

RUN pipdeptree
RUN python setup.py develop --no-deps

RUN cod-demo --help

CMD ["cod-demo"]
```

This is my DockerFile and I am installing ray as a requirement.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Are you using an unofficial image that is created by yourself?

Comment: Hello, thanks :) I edited my question by adding the Dockerfile I use to create the image. I am new to Docker.

Comment: As a matter of fact, it's more convenient to use official [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/rayproject/ray) images as the base image instead of hand-made stuff. do check the link out!

Comment: I am trying to create an image with the official python:3.9 and I am installing my package in it with its requirements. What do you mean by using the official one in this circumstance? Are you talking about the requirements?

Comment: engineers who are developing the RAY project publish regular updates on their product in the form of a docker image! I didn't use RAY in docker but I know the project installation is a tough task that needs a lot of experience. what I suggested above was using the high-quality easy to use docker images that are created by the most experienced RAY users instead of making your hands dirty and creating your own potentially defective one.

Comment: I am now trying to build my image with FROM rayproject/ray instead of FROM python:3.9 but now it is apparently not able to install one of my requirements: cytoolz>=0.11.0.

Comment: with high probability `rayproject/ray` already has what you're seeking for! simply overwrite `--entrypoint` and use it as is!

Comment: You mean that rayproject/ray probebly comes with cytoolz already installed and this is causing the issue? What do you mean by overwriting --entrypoint? Is this a way to avoid certain packages to be reinstalled? Thanks again

Comment: I meant the image you downloaded from `dockerhub` already has everything you may need for running `ray`. If you are using additional packages just add them and then you've been all set!

Answer (score 0):

After pulling the appropriate tag based on your needs from [their repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/rayproject/ray/tags) on `dockerhub`. You can simply run tests with:

```
docker run --shm-size=<shm-size> -t -i rayproject/ray
```

or

```
docker run --shm-size=<shm-size> -t -i --gpus all rayproject/ray:<ray-version>-gpu
```

In case you're using GPU. If you need some additional packages which aren't pre-installed on images you must install them through the terminal inside the image or fabricate a new docker-file with the downloaded image as the base image (the `FROM` command argument).

According to what was mentioned [here](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/installation.html#docker-source-images)!

Comment: I am now using an official ray image as base image but I am still getting the same error when I instantiate pool:

✗ failed cod_simulation-run Job 'cod_simulation-run' failed: | AttributeError: 'StreamCapture' object has no attribute 'fileno' Write "details cod_simulation-run" to inspect the error. Processed 1 jobs (1 failed).

Comment: check if you're using the right image `tag`! Default tests have passed? @ZelioSuter